# Export data to excel through WCF

Tags: c#, silverlight, wcf

Is it possible to execute a sql query at the WCF service level and stream the output as .csv or excel format? So, if the user clicks 'export to excel', I would want to run the query in the service and return the same to client in excel/csv format.

Comment: just did.. too bad SO isn't quick enuf :)

Answer (score 1):

Hope this may be help full for some  [wcformatextensions.codeplex.com](http://wcformatextensions.codeplex.com/)
this is actually out of box box solution to enable CSV/TXT export

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731913.aspx

WCF does support streaming with some restrictions.

Can you give us some background on the project? I'm asking this because there may be better options than receiving bulk data. For example, if you're getting data from a database and placing it into an Excel sheet, it may be better to simply use the database and forget WCF altogether.

If you desire to add a service layer to a database, you should consider OData, or at least placing the Excel logic on the client machine so you can access the records one at a time.

If the concern is for performance, you may wish to consider alternative bindings, such as TPC or IPC, which both use a more efficient binary contract serializer.

If you prefer not to consider alternatives, I would personally use CSV or tab separated format, and appropriately named (.txt, .csv), as working with the Excel format usually requires either a running copy of Excel (interop libraries), or a paid-for third party tool.

Comment: In my application, we execute stored procedures and bind the data to the grid. There is also a requirement that the query be run in the server and prompt the users to download the same in csv format instead of binding it to the grid. I actually did try the approach mentioned in this link http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/103927/236977.aspx. However I get XML parsing errors.